# How can I create the backend area with symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using Symfony2 and FOSUserbundle. So far my front end is working.
I have not used symfony 1 so I have just started with symfony 2.

I don't know how I can make the backend Admin system where I can add remove edit users.
Can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Sonata Admin](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master). It describes itself as "the missing symfony2 admin generator".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Sonata Admin bundle James mentions is the way to go if you ask me.

Comment: can i use it with FOSUserbuundle

Comment: Sure, I wouldn't know why not. I actually have a site running with both.